# Easiest way to compare values of big data type ignoring one field or without that field

Tags: haskell, equality, generic-programming

I'm working with data type from library which has a lot of constructors and each constructor has several fields. Every constructor is defined using *Record Syntax*. And every constructor has field with the same name. I want to check equality of values of this data type but without this one field. I'm just not interested in it. What is the easiest and cleanest way to do? Perfectly, I would be extremely happy if something like this exist:

```
equalsWithout ignoredField value1 value2
```

The easiest way I can imagine is to translate this data type to `[String]` using `Show` and compare result lists. But I would like to avoid this because it require to write a lot of boilerplate code because data type has a lot of constructors... Maybe there's cleaner way to achieve this.

Comment: Is the `ignoredField` known at compile time? Or only at runtime?

Comment: Copy the value from one to the other and then compare: `a { foo = foo b } == b`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `ignoredField` is known at compile time.

Comment: @soupi Amazing! Now I feel stupid :( Should be ashamed of such silly questions. At the same time I really like there's such easy and elegant solution! Can accept as the answer if you post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

per your request:

Copy the value from one to the other and then compare:

`a { foo = foo b } == b`

Comment: Thanks again! Also I want to note that this approach also extends on any number of fields.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the best approach would be to just split that field out of your type.  Instead of

```
data MyData = C1 IgnoredType T1 T2
            | C2 IgnoredType T2 T3
            | C3 IgnoredType T4
```

you could do this:

```
data MySimpleData = C1 T1 T2
                  | C2 T2 T3
                  | C3 T4
    deriving Eq

data WithIgnored a = WI IgnoredType a
instance Eq a => Eq (WithIgnored a) where
    WI _ x == WI _ y = x == y
type MyData = WithIgnored MySimpleData
```

Or less flexibly:

```
data MyData = MD IgnoredType MySimpleData
instance Eq MyData where
    MD _ x == MD _ y = x == y
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I can't split that field. Because I'm working with the data type from library as I mentioned in the question, it's not my own :( Though I agree with you that such design would be better in some sense.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't split out the item you want to avoid comparing then the next best solution is to project the rest of the data into a structure that has a convenient `Eq` instance, like a tuple:

```
import Data.Function (on)

myDataComparables (MyData a b c d) = (b,c,d)

instance Eq MyData where
  (==) = (==) `on` myDataComparables
```

Comment: Well, perhaps the *next* best is @soupi's, but this one is pretty good too. :)

Comment: I don't want to write `myDataComparables` function because data type has dozens of constructors. And I can't use tuples, because those constructors have fields with different types. Though I can convert to `[String]` as I mentioned in the question. Yes, I really like @soupi's answer :)

Comment: Another answer bites the dust. :)